# cvxopt cone programming documentation

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve a quadratic optimisation problem using the cvxopt python library.
I have quadratic constraints which I'm converting to cone constraints.

My question is regarding the cvxopt [documentation for cone programming](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#second-order-cone-programming). The general cone program is described with (among others) the constraints:

> s_0 => 0
>
> s_k0 => || s_k1 || for k = 1,...,M

Do they really mean this?

They give an example under the documentation:

[image]

that they represent as:

```
G = [ matrix( [[12., 13., 12.], [6., -3., -12.], [-5., -5., 6.]] ) ]
G += [ matrix( [[3., 3., -1., 1.], [-6., -6., -9., 19.], [10., -2., -2., -3.]] ) ]
h = [ matrix( [-12., -3., -2.] ),  matrix( [27., 0., 3., -42.] ) ]
```

which seems to suggest that the constraints are instead:

> s_k0 => || s_k1 || for k = 0,...,M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the important part of the example:

```
sol = solvers.socp(c, Gq = G, hq = h)
```

From the [documentation for cone programming](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#second-order-cone-programming):

> The argument `Gq` is a list of *M* dense or sparse matrices *G_1, ..., G_M*. The argument `hq` is a list of *M* dense single-column matrices *h_1, ..., h_M*. The elements of `Gq` and `hq` must have at least one row. The default values of `Gq` and `hq` are empty lists.

So the componentwise inequalities represented by `s_0` are just omitted.